# How to restore USB memory stick partition

Tags: partition-table

I have a USB memory stick which I cannot mount because it appears that it has no partition.

When I plug it in and run 'lsblk' command:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1  14.3G  0 disk
```

No partition

When I run 'fdisk --list':

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.32 GiB, 15376318464 bytes, 30031872 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           1 30031871 30031871 14.3G ee GPT

GPT PMBR size mismatch (30595071 != 30031871) will be corrected by write.
```

Shows the partition but also that there is some size mismatch problem.

I have tried the 'w' command to write and exit (without making any changes), but that doesn't solve the problem.

How can I repair this partition so that I can mount it?

Comment: FYI: https://superuser.com/questions/1352065/gpt-pmbr-size-mismatch-will-be-corrected-by-write

Comment: `gdisk` may help.

Comment: If there is valuable data on the stick I'd do a `dd` to an image file FIRST.  Just in case the recovery fails!